# Como posso deletar uma linha de uma Session?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, session, asp

Tenho uma página SEM BANCO DE DADOS INSERIDO, os dados do cadastro estão sendo armazenados na Session. Estou usando um repeater para armazenar isso. O comando excluir que eu usava antes era através do repeater, o que está errado pois tem que ser feito pela Session senão o funcionamento não está correto. Como posso fazer isso? Já tentei usar Session.Abandon; Session.Remove; Session.RemoveAt  estou começando a usar c# asp.net agora

```
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Ações:</td>
                                <td>Nome:</td>
                                <td> ....</td>
                            </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate > 
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:button ID="btnAlterar" runat="server" CommandName="Alterar" OnCommand="btnAlterar_Click" text="Alterar"></asp:button>
                                    <asp:button ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" CommandName="Excluir" OnCommand="btnExcluir_Click" text="Excluir"></asp:button>
                                </td> 
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nome") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nasci") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cpf") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cidade") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Estado") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Endereco") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Num") %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>    
                    </asp:Repeater>  
    </table>//Table onde está o Repeater e os Botões
```

Repeater itemCommand:

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {

```
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Alterar":
            break;


        case "Excluir":
            Session.Contents.Remove("lst");

            break;
    }
}
```

É assim que os dados estão sendo armazenados na Session:

Pessoa p = new Pessoa();

```
    p.Nome = txtNome.Text;
    p.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    p.Nasci = txtNasci.Text;
    p.Cpf = txtCpf.Text;
    p.Cidade = txtCidade.Text;
    p.Estado = ListEstado.Text;
    p.Endereco = txtEndereco.Text;
    p.Num = Repeater1.Items.Count;

    if (Session["lst"] == null)
    {
        List<Pessoa> lstNova = new List<Pessoa>();
        lstNova.Add(p);

        Session["lst"] = lstNova;

        Repeater1.DataSource = lstNova;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        List<Pessoa> lstTodoMundo = (List<Pessoa>)Session["lst"];
        lstTodoMundo.Add(p);
        Repeater1.DataSource = lstTodoMundo;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma *Session* armazena um objeto, e no seu caso armazena uma *Lista*. Você não vai conseguir alterar nenhum valor da lista usando *Session.RemoveAt* por exemplo, por que aí você vai estar removendo o objeto que está na *Session* (que é a lista) e **não** um item da lista.

Logo, você vai ter que primeiro excluir da *lista* e depois atualizar a *Session* com a lista atualizada.

**1. Identifique o registro do *repeater* que você quer excluir/atualizar colocando um valor para o *CommandArgument***. Eu utilizei a propriedade "Num" do objeto *Pessoa*.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ações:</td>
                    <td>Nome:</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAlterar" runat="server" CommandName="Alterar" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Num") %>' OnCommand="btnAlterar_Command" Text="Alterar"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" CommandName="Excluir" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Num") %>'  OnCommand="btnExcluir_Command" Text="Excluir"></asp:Button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nome") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nasci") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cpf") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cidade") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Estado") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Endereco") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Num") %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

2. No evento *Repeater1_ItemCommand*: recupere o "num" da *Pessoa* recebido no parâmetro *e.CommandArgument*. Depois ache o objeto *Pessoa* na lista (que já está na *Session*) através do "Num". Remova da lista o objeto *Pessoa* encontrado e atualize a *Session* com a lista atualizada.

   protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
       {
           switch (e.CommandName)
           {
               case "Alterar":
                   break;
               case "Excluir":

   ```
               int numero = 0;
               int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out numero);

               var lstPessoas = (List<Pessoa>)Session["lst"];

               // Não se esqueça de importar o namespace System.Linq para usar o Where na lista
               // Importar: using System.Linq; 
               var pessoa = lstPessoas.Where(p => p.Num == numero).FirstOrDefault();

               lstPessoas.Remove(pessoa);

               Session["lst"] = lstPessoas;

               Repeater1.DataSource = lstPessoas;
               Repeater1.DataBind();

               break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Só consegui realizar os testes hoje...mas agradeço muito está funcionando corretamente!  Muito Obrigado :))

Comment: Por nada @GustavoLuiz. Até a próxima ;)